# ggplot geom_line: Change order of plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

**Summary:**

GGplot seems to plot lineplots in an alphabetical order when `aes(group = ID)` is set.
The line for each ID is plotted according to its (alphabetical) order. In my case this results in a quite busy plot. I'd like to have the lines of a specific *group* in the background. More specifically I want those lines in the background which have the most values in their group, so that they are not overlapping the lines from groups with only a few values.

**Question:**

How can I reorder the data in that way that the group with the most values is plotted first?

**Code:**

First some code to generate data to work with (not pretty but the result is good):

```
rm(list=ls()) 
set.seed(42)
library('ggplot2')

numOfValues <- c(20, 6, 3, 2)
System <- c(letters[1:4])
times <- c(1,2,3)
slope <- sample(1:4, size = 4)

df <- data.frame()
row <- 1
for (sys in 1:length(System)) {
  for (num in 1:numOfValues[sys]) {
    for (t in 1:length(times)) {
      # this seems stupid, but to be consistent with my data I need unique but
      # ordered ID's
      df[row, 'ID'] <- paste('P', 
                             num + if (System[sys] == 'a') {0} 
                             else if (System[sys] == 'b') {20} 
                             else if (System[sys] == 'c') {26}
                             else if (System[sys] == 'd') {28} , 
                             sep='_') 
      
      df[row, 'System'] <- System[sys]
      df[row, 'Time'] <- paste('T', times[t], sep = '')
      df[row, 'Value'] <- runif(1, 1, 10) + times[t] + slope[sys]
      row <- row + 1
    }
  }
}
```

This is my plotting code with ggplot

```
p <- ggplot(data = df,
            aes(x = Time,
            y = Value, 
            group = ID,
            colour = System,
            label = ID)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(size = 3,
             aes(shape = System)) +
  theme_bw()

p
```

This is resulting in this graph:

[image: unordered plot]

You can see that some red lines from group *a* a on top and some are more in the background behind purple/green lines.
It seems like that the lines get plotted in the order of the *group* aesthetic from ggplot, in this case by *ID*. This is mentioned here:

[How can I define line plotting order in ggplot2 for grouped lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003991/how-can-i-define-line-plotting-order-in-ggplot2-for-grouped-lines).

As suggested there, I could plot each group in a separate geom_line call but I think there must be an other way. The second solution posted in the above mentioned question got me thinking, but I'm not able to adopt it to my code, since I need to group the (sample) ID's by my Column 'System'.

I thought if I refactor my ID column in the correct order like my groups I can tell ggplot to plot those lines first which correspond to the group with the most values inside.

What else could I try to tell ggplot to plot the lines not by *ID* but by *System*?
How can I order the factored ID's according to their group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in the process of writing the question, and I thought I might share this, since it could be helpfull for other people :°).

It seems like we can refactor the leves according to a different column like this:

```
df$ID <- as.factor(df$ID)
df$System <- as.factor(df$System)

df$ID <- factor(df$ID, 
               levels = c(c(unique(as.factor(df$ID[c(which(df$System == 'a'))]))),
                          c(unique(as.factor(df$ID[c(which(df$System == 'b'))]))),
                          c(unique(as.factor(df$ID[c(which(df$System == 'c'))]))),
                          c(unique(as.factor(df$ID[c(which(df$System == 'd'))])))
                          )
               )
```

Executing this, we're looking for those row's`which` are part of group `a`. Then we take the line number to get the *ID*'s of those samples and pass them as an *unique* (there are multiple samples with the same name) vector to the `levels` parameter. We repeat that for each group.

This results in this plot (take the code from the question):

[image: Ordered Plot]

Now the lines in the largest group *a* are plotted first